# Pattern to match non-ambiguous hexadecimal numbers only (not decimal numbers)

Tags: python, regex, perl

We are all familiar with the regexp for hex numbers, but what's a clever regular expression which only matches non-ambiguous hex numbers but does not match integers (base-10/decimal). Examples

- `1f345` = MATCH
- `0f123` = MATCH
- `12340` = NO MATCH (ambiguous decimal, could be either hex or decimal)
- `01234` = NO MATCH (technically not an integer either)

It seems it requires two regular expressions. First match for hex numbers (and integers) then match the result for at least one `[a-f][A-F]`.  But is there an easier way?

The application of this is to wholesale replacement of non-ambiguous hex numbers to their converted decimal versions while leaving ambiguous numbers in place.

Comment: Given that any decimal number is also a valid hexadecimal number, I feel like you will have some problems ahead.

Comment: I was been euphemistic: it is actually __impossible__ - unless your hexadecimal numbers are marked as such in your syntax in a distinctive manner (like an "H" suffix, or "0x" prefix)

Comment: @jsbueno The ambiguous cases are obviously ambiguous, but the question asks specifically for the unambiguous ones. While I too fail to see any useful applications for this, it's not hard to do.

Comment: @tripleee It's unclear what the OP wants. You say they're asking specifically about the unambiguous cases, but I'm not sure they even realize that 12340 is both valid decimal and valid hex. This seems to be an XY problem based on a misconception.

Comment: The question (plus now erased comments form the OP)  denotes the OP does not know exactly what he is dealing with. Otherwise, it would simply be a question to detect hexadecimal digits. Blindly answering what is asked, even if it si nonsense, won't help the author or further readers.

Comment: Even though this is unmitigated speculation, I can vaguely imagine scenarios where you might have an application ask users for clarification when there is ambiguity; this would then be useful e.g. to avoid asking when there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've updated the question based on feedback.

Comment: Also, that seems like a really terrible idea. You'll go from having a file with some ambiguous values, to a file where *every* value is ambiguous.

Comment: @jsbueno see tripleee answer. Seems good.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I updated the question, and yes every value will be "ambiguous" but only in this context. Really every value can now be interpreted as an decimal even the ones that weren't converted. The actual values are less important then no-hex values are in this file.

Comment: @Gregory That doesn't make any sense. If the values don't matter, you might as well just treat everything as hex and skip the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

As I commented above, unless there is further distinction in your input data between decimal and hexadecimal numbers, it is not possible (as in impossible) to figure out which numbers are hexadecimal.

While hexadecimal numbers allow extra digits beyond the Arabic digits 0-9, numbers formed only by these are also valid hexadecimal numbers, with a different value than the same number if it was a decimal representation.

That is why all programming languages (and data files) that allow for both decimal and hexadecimal numbers to be present (among other possible bases like octal and binary) have distinct markers for them. For example, in C and languages derived from C, the prefix "0x" is used, so anyone can spot the difference between 0x1234 and 1234.

If you really have input data mixing both numeric bases like this, you have to go a step back and figure out a way of telling which number means what, possibly as part of some other context. If there is no such context and no way to regenerate your input data, you  may as well just quit whatever you are trying to achieve.

**update** - This text had been written when the question text was written in another form, and it was not easy to understand the real intent. The question is much ore clear now - I will keep the answer since it may be good advice for novices trying a magic way to tell hexadecimal from decimal, without any extra markup.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Can you show some impossible-to-judge case?

Comment: It was already shown by him. Take `1234`. It can be a decimal number (then it's decimal 1234), or hexadecimal (then it's decimal 4660), or octal (then it's decimal 668), or all other kinds of more obscure bases.

Comment: `10`. Is `10` in dec. Is `16` in hex. It's `8` in octal. And it's `2` in binary.

Comment: @CherryDT Are you talking to me? 1234 is valid decimal and thus clearly "NO MATCH". Just like the 12340 in the question.

Comment: Yeah well, now it is. Because the OP added the "non-ambigous" part in.

Answer (score 3):

Require at least one hex digit, bracketed by zero or more hex or dec digits on both sides.

```
[0-9]*[a-f][0-9a-f]*
```

Updated with the optimization suggested by @AdrianHHH.

Comment: For performance and less backtracking `[0-9]*[a-f][0-9a-f]*` might be better.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Excellent; updated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this could possibly be useful, but you can use

```
/^[0-9]*[a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*\z/
```